# Reading global environment variables

Tags: c, linux, unix, gnu

I have a process which is created by execve() from another program and a specific set of environment is passed to it. However, I would need to read a global environment variable that may or may not be set by the user based on certain aspects. For example, $PATH is set when the execve() is called, but if the user stes `$LOWMEM=1` (`export LOWMEM=1`) 
before the program is exec'ed, then the program will not make `malloc()` calls larger than `1KB`.

when I do a `getenv("LOWMEM")` call from the program it returns `NULL` where as I have added `LOWMEM=1` in `/etc/enviroment` and `echo $LOWMWM` shows the value as 1. But I don't see LOWMEM entry in `/proc/<PID>/environ`. Whereas I had rebooted the system after adding the entry to the `/etc/environment`.

Is it not possible to read global environment from a process running under specific environment without explicitly passing it from the parent process?

Comment: There's no such thing as a global environment. Every process has its own environment. By default a process inherits a copy of its parent's environment, but `execve()` can override this.

Comment: How do you set the `LOWMEM` environment variable in the shell?  Assuming a POSIX-ish shell, you must use `export LOWMEM=1` to create an environment variable; simply using `LOWMEM=1` without an `export LOWMEM` somewhere doesn't create an environment variable. (If you prefer seashells, then you need `setenv LOWMEM 1` and not just `set LOWMEM 1`.)  Adding `LOWMEM` to `/etc/environment` and rebooting seems like overkill — it isn't a good way of doing business.

Comment: Is `LOWMWM` a typo for `LOWMEM`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that you're clearing out the entry for LOWMEM while using `execve`. Instead, it might be better to call `setenv` for the new variables you want, either in the parent or in the child and then call `execv`.